# IntegrityError - 1048, cannot be null - Unable to save validated_data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to accept the below mentioned JSON data from the user and want to save it into database (MySql).

```
{
"organisation_name":"abc pqr"
}
```

When I make a POST request it return me the error -

```
IntegrityError at /api/organisation/
(1048, "Column 'organisation_id' cannot be null")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/organisation/
Django Version: 2.1.15
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
(1048, "Column 'organisation_id' cannot be null")
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute, line 76
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 5 Jan 2020 20:26:14 +0000
```

**views.py**

```
from typing import Optional, Any
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

from . import serializers


class OrganisationApiView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, formate=None):
        return Response({"message": "You are Cool!!"})

    def post(self, request, formate=None):

        serializer = serializers.OrganisationSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            organisation_saved = serializer.save()
            organisation_name = serializer.validated_data.get('organisation_name')
            message = f"Onboarding for {organisation_name} has been successful!."
            return Response({'message': message, 'response': organisation_saved, 'status': status.HTTP_200_OK})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.error_messages)

    def put(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({'message': 'PUT'})

    def patch(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({'message': 'PATCH'})

    def delete(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({'message': 'Delete'})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator, validate_image_file_extension
from django.db import models


class BaseModel(models.Model):

    """"This model will get the data/row created date for all the models defined in this model"""

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Organisation(models.Model):

    """This model will store the name of the tenant (organisation name). The data of this model could be further
    utilized for creating a VM, Object Storage Bucket and a Database"""

    organisation_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    organisation_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True, blank=False)


class Permission(models.Model):

    """This model list all the groups of the permissions. These permissions are further assigned to the users in User
    model."""

    permission_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    permission_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)


class User(models.Model):

    """The data of the users belonging to the various Organisation will be stored here along with their login
    credentials. This model also identifies the roles of the users in their respective organisation. The users
    in the model can be classified or grouped according to the organisation."""

    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        validators=[EmailValidator]
    )
    profile_picture = models.TextField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[validate_image_file_extension]
    )
    password = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    user_organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_role = models.ForeignKey(Permission, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Organisation

class OrganisationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # organisation_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    organisation_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, allow_null=False, allow_blank=False)

    class Meta:
        fields: '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):

        """This method will insert Organisation Details into model Organisation"""

        return Organisation.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I have overridden the default primary key of Django model in my each model class. I just want to accept the `organisation_name`  from the user and the `organisation_id` should be generated according to the principles of **Primary key**. I don't understand why is it asking for the organisation_id as I have already mentioned it as a **Primary Key** in my Django model . I have also tried by sending the `organisation_id` with the `organisation_name` in the JSON but it still return the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set it to `Autofield` if you want that Django handle its generation, otherwise you are responsible for function that generates unique id's

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

In Your case of big int

```
organisation_id  = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested in my Organisation model. Also, I am able to insert the object into database. But it also generates an error as TypeError: Object of type Organisation is not JSON serializable .